# jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not load to Wildfly 10.x

Tags: jboss, cxf, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 10 with Java 8. WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml is below, i also tried to put jboss-deployment-structure.xml under META-INF.
I want to use JBoss AS as a servlet container with no WS functionalities, so i try to turn off the webservices subsystem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sub-deployment name="my.war">
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But i still get the below error. I think xml doesn't load.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYWS0059: Apache CXF library (cxf-2.6.2.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try with:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="webservices"/>
      <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
      <module name="org.apache.cxf"/>
      <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl"/>      
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

PS: The correct place is under WEB-INF

Comment: Actually I have another similar problem, this time it has WS functionalities.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063542/application-migration-from-tomcat-7with-jdk-1-7-to-wildfly-10with-jdk-1-8      Should i add dependicies this time?

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying a **ear** (containing "my.war") or a standalone **war** ? 
Because you're using `<sub-deployment>` and not `<deployment>`...

I would have done it like this (here limited to REST web services)

```
    <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
      <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        ...
```

Comment: I'm deploying a standalone war. I also tried <deployment>, but still don't working :(